# How do I solve this Devise authentication challenge?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Hello people I have some challenges here with devise authentication for users:

I have two models called color and sub_color in my application. the sub_color belongs_to color and color has_many sub_colors.I have already seeded the database with the appropriate data

The challenge; I want a user to be able to chose these in the devise form_for when they are registering as a collection object and the id of the sub_color will be used for identifying a particular user also(a situation where for instance I can sort all the users which cosed blue color). How do I achieve this please?

This is what I have tried but it is not working:

```
 %= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
                          <%= f.error_notification %>

                          <div class="form-inputs">
                            <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
                            <%= f.input :user_name, required: true %>
                            <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#      {@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length) %>
                            <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
                            <%= f.input :first_name, required: true %>

     <%= f.label :color_id, "Color" %> <br/>
     <%= f.collection_select :color_id, Color.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: true%>

     <%= f.label :sub_color_id, "Sub Color" %> <br/>
     <%= f.grouped_collection_select :sub_color_id, Color.order(:name), :sub_color, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: true%>

     <div class="form-actions">
                        <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
                      </div>

model for users:
 belongs_to :sub_color
 has_one :color, through: :sub_color

 devise.......

end


model for sub_color

has_many :users
belongs_to :color

end


model for color

has_many :sub_color

end
```

This is the error I see on the web browser

```
NoMethodError in Devise::Registrations#new
[undefined method `color_id' for #<User:0xbacc720>]
```

Comment: Do you have `color_id`  and `sub_color_id` in your User Model?

Comment: No I didn't have it but they are present now..Thanks but I still have the challenge I used RSB's answer to add it to the models.

Comment: Can your update question with your  User, Color and SubColor Models and their Fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, You need to add `color_id` and `sub_color_id` to users table.

Then define association, in user.rb `belongs_to :sub_color` and in sub_color.rb `has_many :users`. Same goes with `color`, user.rb `belongs_to :color` and in color.rb `has_many :users` .

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have done all the above thanks but it is still showing no method error.

Comment: NoMethodError in Devise::Registrations#new
Showing C:/Users/...../new.html.erb where line #19 raised:

undefined method `color_id' for #<User:0x851f928>
Rails.root: C:/Users/c/Documents/Ojojas

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
activemodel (4.2.6) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/base.rb:28:in `public_send'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/base.rb:28:in `value'
actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/collection_select.rb:16:in `block in render'

Comment: That's because you need to remove color id

Comment: Then how do I implement the collection  object? Please kindly give example.

Comment: Yes it is  a mandatory field.  During their  registration they need to  select a color then the color determines the sub_color they will  chose from.  Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my answer, you need to add `color_id` in users table and define associations as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: are you there? Please I have encountered some new issue. I was wondering if you could help too. I tried to access sub_color field from users controller but it is giving undefined method. I did user.sub_color.name. am I doing this right?

Comment: Is `sub_color_id` is present for that user?

Comment: Yes it is present.

Comment: I noticed there was no value in Sub_color_id field for users. I add it for the users and I can access it now. Thanks.