# How do I effectively implement bootstrap toggle data in ruby on rails loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Hi people I have some challenges here.I used a data-toggle collapse loop on my apps index.html.erb page.Now it works for the first instance of the loop only. That means each time I click on it, it opens and close.But if I click on the others only the the same first one at the top is affected(works)The others don't work.This is the code below: In case you want to take a look at my model it is here [How do I solve this Devise authentication challenge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609816/how-do-i-solve-this-devise-authentication-challenge/39610809#39610809)

```
  <% @sub_color.each do |c| %><% unless sub_color.color.nil? %>
    <table class="table">
      <thead >
        <tr >
          <th >Names</h2></th >
          <th >Names 2</th >
          <th >Names 3</th >
        </tr >
      </thead >
      <tbody >
        <tr >
          <td >             
            <a href="#demo"data-toggle="collapse"><%= c.color.title%></a>
            <div id="demo" class="collapse">
              <%=c.title %>
            </div>
          </td >
```

Comment: Its because of `href="#demo"`.. so everytime its gonna collapse the first element with this id..

Comment: What do I do please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u can easily do this.. if the `@sub_color` have id..

```
<td >             
   <a href="#demo_<%= c.id %>" data-toggle="collapse"><%= c.color.title%></a>
   <div id="demo_<%= c.id %>" class="collapse">
      <%=c.title %>
   </div>
</td >
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your problem is that all of your collapsible `div`s have the same `id`. You probably need to do something like:

```
  <%= link_to c.color.title, "#demo-#{c.color.id}", data: {toggle: "collapse"} %>
  <%= content_tag :div, c.title, class: "collapse", id: "demo-#{c.color.id}" %>
```

I haven't used erb in a long time (I use HAML instead), so the syntax might be a little off.

This bit:

```
  <%= link_to c.color.title, "#demo-#{c.color.id}", data: {toggle: "collapse"} %>
```

Should give you something like (assuming c.color.id is 1 and c.color.title is Red):

```
  <a href="#demo-1" data-toggle="collapse">Red</a>
```

And this bit:

```
  <%= content_tag :div, c.title, class: "collapse", id: "demo-#{c.color.id}" %>
```

Should give you something like (assuming c.title is Blue):

```
  <div id="demo-1" class="collapse">Blue</div>
```

Or something along those lines.